# Sprite can jump up through platform onto platform, once while it's on platform, but falls through second time

Tags: jumping, platform

Sorry, I'm kind of new to this whole thing and trying to learn both Unity and its use of C#. I have overlapping box colliders set up and a trigger on the lower one to allow me to jump through the lower platform. That works fine, and once on the platform, I can jump through it and land on the top, and I can make a singular jump while I am on the platform, but as soon as I jump a second time, I fall right through. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about fixing this? I originally thought it was that the overlap on the two colliders was too much, or that the radius of my ground points were too large, but fixing both of those didn't do me any good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are developing for 2D or 3D?

Comment: Experimented with the collision detection of the player (Switched from discrete to continuous), and found that to fix the problem too!

Comment: This is the first step friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing in 2D environment then try to implement `Platform Effector`. In you Platform Sprite, attach a `BoxCollider2D` and mark check on `Used By Effector` and attach `Platform Effector 2D` like this, you are all done. [image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems like it's helping a lot, but I'm still sort of falling through the platform occasionally. I have two box-colliders set up like this; I assumed that the effector would be used with the collision box instead of the trigger box (Though I did try with the trigger box and it made the platform intangible to the sprite). So far this is my setup: (Sorry, gotta figure out how to incorporate this! One sec)

Comment: Yea, it must not be Trigger

Comment: If I uncheck trigger it doesn't let me walk in front of (through) the platform. Is  there a way to fix that? Or do I have to pick which one I'd rather have?

Comment: Your one collider is normal `Trigger`, change, uncheck `Trigger` and mark check on`User By Effector`

Comment: (Here's my setup, I don't know if that'll be helpful at all; the bigger lower box is the one I have triggered to allow me to walk through it, the upper one is the one that causes collision) http://imgur.com/a/fpr4I

Comment: Still can't seem to walk through the platform but I'd much rather be able to jump on the platform without falling through! Thanks!

Comment: @RainbowElephant why you have two colliders instead of two sprites? If you don't have flat platform then I'd suggest to have different sprites as different platforms

Comment: I was following the youtube tutorials by inScope Studios and they suggested using the two colliders with a triggers script where touching the lower collider box would turn off the collision for the top box. I'll keep that in mind for next time, though. Thanks!